# Erro ao enviar pdf pelo Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou recebendo o erro 

A problem was encountered while attempting to move the uploaded file to the final destination

 ao tentar enviar um pdf pelo formulário.

Segue a função que envia o currículo: https://pastebin.com/4vv3DXPq
E a página https://pastebin.com/rURwqLG4

Estranho, porque estou usando Wamp e a pasta está com permissão de leitura e escrita.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia! Wamp é para Windows, e em Windows o caractere de dois pontos `:` é inválido para criar um nome de arquivo. Verifique a linha:

```
$nome_curriculo = date('Y-m-d_H:i:s').'.pdf';
```